# Не проигрывается стрим радио в плеере Actionscript 3.0

Tags: javascript, actionscript

Добрый день!

Написал радиоплеер, основанный на технологии flash, используется actionscript 3.0. В браузерах Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, при переключений со станции на станцию играет, а когда возвращаешься обратно на станцию, которую уже слушал, она не играет, помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот исходник ActionScript:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.*;

//===========================================================
var radioLink: String = "";
var allFlashVars: Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var volume = String(allFlashVars["volume"]);
var playFlag: Boolean = false;
var soundControl: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var context: SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(2500, false);
var soundControlTransform = new SoundTransform();

linkRecieve.text = radioLink;
txtVolume.text = volume;

soundControlTransform.volume = volume / 100;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendLinkFromJS", receiveLinkFromJS);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendVolumeFromJS", receiveVolumeFromJS);

function receiveLinkFromJS(radioLink: String, playFlag: Boolean): void {
    try {
        if (playFlag) {
            linkRecieve.text = radioLink;
            sound == null;
            var sound: Sound = new Sound();
            sound.load(new URLRequest(radioLink), context);
            soundControl.stop();
            soundControl = sound.play();
            soundControl.soundTransform = soundControlTransform;
        } else {
            linkRecieve.text = "";
            sound == null;
            soundControl.stop();
        }
    } catch (errObject: Error) {
        trace("Error: " + errObject.message);
    }

}

function receiveVolumeFromJS(volume: Number): void {
    txtVolume.text = String(volume);
    soundControlTransform.volume = volume / 100;
    soundControl.soundTransform = soundControlTransform;
}
```

Comment: а пару тройку урлов на станции?, чтоб у себя собрать для тест

Comment: http://fm.kiwi.kz/snakenet/
http://fm.kiwi.kz/dronezone/
http://fm.kiwi.kz/radiosk/

Comment: @baksis2, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй в таком виде:

```
private var sound:Sound = new Sound(); 
private var channel:SoundChannel;

protected function stationList_changeHandler(station:String):void
        {
            var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true);

            if ( channel != null ) 
            {
                channel.stop();
                sound.close();
            }

            sound = new Sound();

            sound.load(new URLRequest(station), context);

            channel = sound.play(); 
        }
```